# Ensuring similar block height of horizontally aligned DIVs with unknown content length

Tags: html, css, height, overflow, expander

On a website i'd like to show products in the following structure:

```
[IMAGE]
[PRODUCT TITLE]
[PRODUCT ID]
[DETAIL TEXT]
[FEATURE LIST]
[PRICE]
```

Resulting in a product display such as:

[image]

Now, the thing is that there are multiple products on display, just like this one, but sometimes they are aligned next to one another.

The problem is that i would like to make the price appear at the same position (vertical wise) in all blocks. Of course i see only one solution at first - overflow:hidden on the detail text / feature listing. But then i'd end up having content cut off, right?

Another problem is that there should also be a more>> button (expander) that appears if the UL/LI-listing is longer than 4 entries. Just like this:

[image: image2]

I thought this through quite often, but i seem to find no proper solution. For one i will never know if an LI will be multiline, as the content might be longer or shorter - and i cannot calculalate this serverside, as the font width/height might vary.

I'd appreciate any constructive input here.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have a fixed width you could use `inline-block` mixed with negative margins : http://jsfiddle.net/bymaK/11/

[image]

The sad thing is that it works in Chrome, Opera and IE 9 but completely break Firefox as it's management of with:0 and negative margin seem buggy (Added [issue #709014](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709014) to Bugzilla following this post). The solution is to detect this browser and set the width to 1px for it...

It create a small bug as when you resize there is 1 pixel where the price warp to the next line but not the block but it's a lot less visible that the result otherwise :

[image]

---

```
<div id="container">
    <p>texttexttext</p>
    <ul>
        <li>texttexttext</li>
        <li>texttexttext</li>
        <li>texttexttext<Update/li>
        <li>texttexttext</li>
        <li><a href="#" class="more">more &raquo;</a></li>
        <li class="more">more text</li>
        <li class="more">Even more text.</li>
    </ul>
</div><p class="price">$3993.99</p>
```

```
.price
{
    height:40px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#container
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul
{
    list-style-type:disc;
    margin-left:30px
}
li.more
{
    display: none;
}
```

```
$(function(){
    $('a.more').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('li').hide().nextAll('li').show(200);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. I don't think i can apply it, yet it sure works well. I think this is the most fitting solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have the containing div set to `position: relative`, and then price set to `position: absolute; bottom:0`? That way, no matter how much text is in the box, the price is always at 0 (or whatever number you set).

Here's a rudimentary example:  http://jsfiddle.net/PFwJ6/1/

Comment: But in that case if i have 4 such product displays horizontally aligned next to one another, the price would still not be placed at the same vertical position, correct?

Comment: Thank you for this. The problem is, if the content is longer, i will end up with different positions again, as the outer block height will increase. See [http://jsfiddle.net/GHnb5/](http://jsfiddle.net/GHnb5/)

Comment: Ah. I was under the impression that the content would all be the same length. Sorry about that.

Comment: I wish it was. Perhaps there is not even any proper solution to this, in the way expected?

Comment: @user1018787 see my answer, not perfect but looking like it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use javascript to find the height and display a "click to view more link".

First, create a div over the price div that would contain your "click to see more" link and set it to `display:none`. Then you can use `offsetHeight` in javascript to find the height of the div. If the height is over what is acceptable then you would set the div to `display:block`. That means you can set all of your containing divs to the same height with the price div pinned to the bottom using positioning.

I'm sorry I don't have concrete code for you. I might be able to put some together shortly. But this should point you in the right direction.